# Error Uploading Arduino Sketch to Arduino Pro Mini

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-pro-mini

I got an error "stk500_getsync() not in sync resp=0x00" when I tried to update an Arduino Pro Mini with an FTDI Basic Breakout 5V/3.3V - Micro USB. Maybe someone has instructions on how to resolve this issue. I use the last version of Arduino IDE.
All standard stuff like drivers, ports installed and configured.

I have communication with controller and I receive answers from it, but when I try to flash the firmware I get that error.

Answer (score 0):

It's your COM port or your board selection.

I often use the Pro Mini and an Uno and when I forget to change either the COM port or the board to which I have to upload the sketch to, that error message happens.

Comment: I updated question.

Comment: Maybe wrong driver. There is only one FTDI driver.